# Can you queue a Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server build remotely with powershell?

Tags: powershell, tfs, continuous-integration

Given Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 (on premises), is it possible to interact with the build and release process remotely with powershell?

For instance, we have CI builds in place with various triggers...e.g.  a working branch is merged to a feature branch will kick off a build.  If I am working on a one off branch that is not part of the trigger set, can I queue a build with a script that I execute on my machine?  Can I do things with the results of that build...e.g. queue the release that is created as a result of the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can via the TFS Rest API.
I implemented the following Task with Powershell: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks

You can have a look at the source as well.

You can find the references to the API on msdn:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/overview

Regards